# How to determine why port 443 is already in use?

Tags: windows-7, port, apache-http-server, sockets, netstat

I'm running Apache 2.4.10 on a Windows 7 machine and am trying to add SSL connections. Port 80 connections work fine, and I'm trying to add port 443.  When the httpd.conf gets `Listen 443` added it fails to start up:

```
c:\Apache24\bin> httpd.exe -k start
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

A check using `netstat` at first revealed Chrome using port 443, so I quit Chrome and after the time out elapsed, the ports are now empty using `netstat`, but the server still fails to start when `Listen 443` is present:

```
c:\Apache24\bin> netstat -ano | grep 443
```

How can I determine who is already on port 443 and blocking the Apache Server from using that port?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue appears to have been Apache conflicting with itself due to there being two `Listen 443` directives, the one I added and one via include:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-sni.conf
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

In the `conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` appears the conflicting line:

```
Listen 443 https
```

Dropping the `Listen 443` I added resolved the issue.

Comment: I didn't realize sni include was redundent with ssl include. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Good one, informational ..

Comment: this worked for me too, i also added a Listen 443 thinking that it was needed but extra\httpd-ssl.conf already has it

Answer (score 1):

c:\Apache24\bin> netstat -ano | grep 443

will list all processId bind 443, like:

```
 TCP    xxx:xxx     xxx:443      ESTABLISHED     4332
 TCP    xxx:xxx     xxx:443      ESTABLISHED     7164
```

then execute:

c:\Apache24\bin> tasklist | grep -e "4332" -e "7164"

will list all process by Id. like:

```
MyPopo.exe                    4332 Console                    1     87,424 K
firefox.exe                   7164 Console                    1    522,576 K
```

Answer (score 0):

Tcpview from sysinternals shows all network related stuff, including which program is using the ports:

```
http://live.sysinternals.com
```

Answer (score -1):

I had multiple entries of the below in `httpd.conf`. After commenting one entry it started working.

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolving The Problem
Procedure:

1. Rename ssl.conf file to ssl.conf.bak
2. Start httpd